# Use count method and for each loop to count the number of element in the array

Tags: java, arrays, methods, foreach, count

I know how to count the number of element in the array without for each loop, but I have to use for each loop for this. This is what I've got so far. I couldn't figure out how I can use for each loop to count the number of elements in the array. Outcome should be 6. I would appreciate any help. Thank you so much.

```
public class Count{
 public Count(){
    int a[] = {7, 8, 9, 9, 8, 7};
    System.out.println(count(a));        
 }

 public int count(int count[]){
    for (int c : count)
    return c;
 }
}
```

Comment: `int counter = 0; for (int c : count) { counter++;} return counter;`...?

Comment: It's the same thing as using a regular for loop. Just initialize a variable outside the loop, increment it on the inside, then return it at the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int count(int count[])
{
    int i = 0;
    for (int c : count) {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

this will increase the `i` by 1 for every element in array, and eventually, then return `i`, which will be 6 (in your case)